# Android Renderscript rotateLeft

Tags: android, renderscript

How do I implement this Java function:

```
    public static int rotateLeft(int i, int distance) {
        // Shift distances are mod 32 (JLS3 15.19), so we needn't mask -distance
        return (i << distance) | (i >>> -distance);
    }
```

In [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as C, so something like

```
static int rotateLeft(int i, int distance) {
  return (i << (distance % 32)) | ((unsigned int)i >> (32 - (distance % 32)));
}
```